# Kubuntu 15.10 install on Win7

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu

Is it possible to install Kubuntu 15.10 on my win7 Acer laptop? Do I need a previous version of kubuntu or will it install with a dual boot? Thanx, Dann.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a dual-boot install, or replace Windows 7, it's entirely up to you.

I would recommend having at least 75 Gb free on your hard drive, and doing at least 50 Gb on a partition dedicated to Ubuntu.

Download and burn the [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/) ISO to a disc, or you can use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to load the ISO data onto a USB drive (Rufus will also make it bootable).

The Kubuntu installer will allow you to partition your hard drive, and has the option to install Kubuntu alongside Windows 7, or replace: It is entirely up to you.